# Linux zombies processes left unterminated with Java ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, processbuilder, zombie-process

I have a java Spring REST API with a controller that runs a linux command with the ProcessBuilder class

. The command is a generated 'find' command

The problem is that I found a lot of unterminated  processes in the hosting server after fiew days of use. I don't know why they  still there and not ended or destroyed . (I checked with a ps -ef command)

Here is my runCmd function:

```
public static final BufferedReader runCmd(String cmd) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
        processBuilder.command("bash", "-c",  cmd);

        processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process process = processBuilder.start();

        BufferedReader output = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

        int ret = process.waitFor();
        return output;
}
```

Is there a way to make sur that there is no more process left behind ?

**UPDATE**

The problem comes only from commands with a very large output stream (std output) Thanks for the hint @DuncG

As this output is important, I can't ignore it. I have to find a way to consume it.

Any Idea on how to do it with Runnable Threads ?

Thanks

Comment: call `process.destroy()` ?

Answer (score 3):

Are your commands generating a lot of output? The cause of the zombies may be simply that cmd has written a lot of output the STDOUT and the stream is blocking in the BufferedReader.

You can test if this the case by adding redirect to null - just append " > /dev/null" the end of cmd. This discards the sub-process output and means the BufferedReader is not full of unread data / blocking the sub-process.

```
processBuilder.command("bash", "-c",  cmd + " > /dev/null");
```

If that fixes the zombie problem you can revert the redirect and make `ProcessBuilder` redirect output to files (before calling `start()`), or you'll need to add a thread to consume the IO as it is generated.

```
Path tmpdir = Path.of(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));
Path out = tmpdir.resolve("stdout.log");
processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
processBuilder.redirectOutput(out.toFile());
```

At the end you should return the out file for caller to check, or could return `Files.newBufferedReader(out)`.

If you don't use the redirect to file as above, this will store using thread to capture the output into memory buffer. Note you'd need to duplicate for STDERR too if not redirecting ERR->OUT:

```
Process p = pb.start();
ByteArrayOutputStream stdout = new ByteArrayOutputStream(8192);
new Thread(() -> copy(p.getInputStream(), stdout), "STDOUT").start();
int rc = p.waitFor();
byte[] sour = stdout.toByteArray()
```

Using method:

```
private static void copy(InputStream in, OutputStream buf)
{
    try(var autoClose = in; var autoClose2 = buf)
    {
        in.transferTo(buf);
    }
    catch(IOException io)
    {
        throw new UncheckedIOException(io);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes , it happens when the  find command returns a big amount of data in the standard output.  I ve found after that the java program was hanging and by killing the manually the find process the java program continue till the end .

Comment: Thanks for the Thread solution. But I've found why command hangs. It turns out that the standard output buffer has a max size of ~64kb. when it's full , it waits until some of it data is readed. otherwise the process will stand waiting and hangs. So I've juste have to consume it  between the process.start and waitFor and  it's works (with a ````bufferedReader.readline````) . Now  , Im wondering why it's so simple, most of solutions I've found in the internet propose the using of Threads ?

Comment: You will need threads if consuming stderr independently in case it or stdout blocks before you have chance to read them

Comment: Yeah, So if I understand, there is no need of threads if I m redirecting the stderror to stdouput with ````processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true)````

Comment: Yes you should be Ok reading one stream without the thread if errors are re-directed to stdout and if you're happy not to know what was just in stderr.